# Wordpress file functions.php is not loading the style.css

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I can't seem to get the `functions.php` file of my WordPress theme load my stylesheet.

The files I've created in the theme directory of my WordPress theme are as follow with their respective contents;

style.css

```
/*
Theme Name: Theme Study
Author: A
Version: 1.0.0
*/

body {
    color: #4d5a6c !important;
}
```

header.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>This is the header</h2>
```

index.php

```
<?php get_header();

while ( have_posts() ) {
    the_post(); ?>
    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
    <?php the_content();
}
get_footer(); ?>
```

footer.php

```
    <h4>This is the footer</h4>
<?php wp_footer(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

functions.php

```
<?php 
function style_files() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style_main', get_stylesheet_uri() );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'style_files' );
```

On the other hand, I've realised that when I reference directly the stylesheet inside the header.php`file as below, it works as expected, but my aim is to achieve that in the`functions.php` file of my WordPress theme.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_uri(); ?>" />
    <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
<body>

<h2>This is the header</h2>
```

Why my `style.ccs` not getting loaded from the `functions.php` file?

Comment: I have tried with above code and its working fine. I am getting style.css file

Comment: Is there a way to see or debug what is wrong?

Comment: make sure your style.css reside on theme root folder and request you to provide your page view source so will get better idea.

Comment: I put the source code

Comment: What if you try to set `WP_DEBUG` at wp-config.php to `true`? So it should be: `define('WP_DEBUG', true);`. Do you see any error messages?

Comment: I change the define('WP_DEBUG', true); and it doesn't show any errors

Comment: Interesting. Do you have any plugins activated that might be overtaking stylesheet output? Did you try deactivating all the plugins?

Comment: Are you using IIS?

Comment: I'm start a study from zero, any plugins installed,Iand 'm using xampp

Comment: If I put this tag " <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_uri(); ?>" />" in the head, than it will work, but i learned that the correct way is to insert wp_head and make wp_enqueue_style in the functions.php

Answer (score 0):

please replace this function with your wp_enqueue_style function.

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_stylesheet_uri() );
```

Comment: Still not loading

Comment: I am on localhost

Comment: check the link in inspect element mode in browser.

Comment: If I put this tag " <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_uri(); ?>" />" in the head, than it will work, but i learned that the correct way is to insert wp_head and make wp_enqueue_style in the functions.php

Answer (score 0):

Use this code I think its work fine for you.

```
function theme_styles(){ 
// Load all of the styles that need to appear on all pages
wp_enqueue_style( 'main', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
wp_enqueue_style( 'custom', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/custom.css' ); 
}
 add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_styles');
```

Comment: Still not loading

Comment: Check your css path. i am already using this its work fine for me

Comment: If I put this tag " <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_uri(); ?>" />" in the head, than it will work, but i learned that the correct way is to insert wp_head and make wp_enqueue_style in the functions.php

Answer (score 0):

Use `get_template_directory_uri()` instead of `get_stylesheet_uri()` as in your `functions.php` file.

Below, a snippet illustrating how it should read;

```
function style_files() {
    wp_enqueue_style(
        'style_main',
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
        array(),
        false,
        'all'
    );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'style_files' );
```

It is a safe way to add/enqueue a stylesheet file to your WordPress theme.

The above follows this format:

```
wp_enqueue_style( $handle, $src, $deps, $ver, $media );
```

where

```
$handle
(string) (Required) Name of the stylesheet. Should be unique.

$src
(string) (Optional) Full URL of the stylesheet,
or path of the stylesheet relative to the WordPress root directory.

Default value: ''

$deps
(array) (Optional) An array of registered stylesheet handles this stylesheet depends on.

Default value: array()

$ver
(string|bool|null) (Optional) String specifying stylesheet version number, if it has one,
which is added to the URL as a query string for cache busting purposes. If version is set to
false, a version number is automatically added equal to current installed WordPress version.
If set to null, no version is added.

Default value: false

$media
(string) (Optional) The media for which this stylesheet has been defined. 
Accepts media types like 'all', 'print' and 'screen', or media queries like
'(orientation: portrait)' and '(max-width: 640px)'.

Default value: 'all'
```

More information available [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/#more-information).

Comment: If I put <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_uri(); ?>" /> in the head it will work, it seem the wp_head();doens´t work

Comment: You don't need to do that once you did in your `functions.php` file. It should work. You may want to add a solid background colour (eg: `body{color: #4d5a6c !important;background-color:red;}`) to checking closer loading of the `style.css` file of your theme. Head over to the [WordPress codex site](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development) for more detail.

Comment: @AlêMoraes: kindly feedback after troubleshooting with a solid background colour. Also, my comment above assumes you have the folder containing your custom WordPress theme inside the `wp-content/themes` directory of your WordPress installation with `index.php`, `style.css`, `functions.php`, `footer.php`, and `header.php` as files.

Answer (score 0):

What if you try to put this at your function.php file:

```
<?php 
function style_files(){
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css');
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'style_files');
```

The one with style id named: **parent-style** usually is for parent theme ( if you are developing child theme or just single theme ), 2nd one is if you are developing child theme and should load `style.css` at your child theme.

Comment: I'm making a theme from zero, all my files are in the root of the theme folder

Comment: So you just need the one with **"parent-style"** in my snippet. You can just name it with **"main-style"** or anything else you like. Have you tried that? And you should ensure that your style name is unique ( no duplication of style id )

Comment: It´s a fresh study, I don´t have any files, just those above, i change the line "parent-style", but it doesn't work, it seem the wp_head is not working

Comment: That is kind of weird. Maybe you should try to call `wp_enqueue_script` too to ensure if `wp_head` doesn't work.